# Haskell Flatten Lists of string

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I want to flatten lists of string but with additional requirements. example

`[["My","Name","is"],["John","Doe"]]`

output :
`My name is \nJohn Doe`

I try using concat function, but still no luck

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [**`unwords :: [String] -> String`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:unwords) to convert a list of `String`s into a single `String`, and then use [**`intercalate :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intercalate) to join the lines together with a separator in between, like:

```
tolines :: [[String]] -> String
tolines = intercalate "\n" . map unwords
```

Comment: Also, if you want/can tolerate an extra `"\n"` at the end, you can replace `intercalate "\n"` with `unlines`

Answer (score 6):

The function you are looking for is called [`intercalate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intercalate) and it lives in `Data.List`. You will have to use it twice.  first to add a space between each word of the inner lists then again to add a `\n` between the outer lists.  `fmap` is your friend.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning `unlines` as an alternative to `intercalate "\n"`.

Comment: @bradm: `unlines` will add an extra `'\n'` at the end. Although of course that is not per se a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Combining the answer of @John F Miller, you just have to do intercalate and add the element you need, and use concatMap:

```
import Data.List

ls = [["My","Name","is"],["John","Doe"]]

rs = concatMap (intercalate " ") (insertAt 1 ["\n"] ls)

insertAt _ _ []     = []
insertAt 0 e xs     = e:xs
insertAt n e (x:xs) = x : (insertAt (n-1) e xs)


main = do
  putStrLn rs

$> My Name is
   John Doe
```

Another option in the comment by @luqui, but I would think in:

```
rs = intercalate " " . intercalate ["\n"] $ ls
```

Comment: How about `intercalate "\n" . map (intercalate " ")` ?

Comment: @luqui sounds great, with that idea I updated the answer, forgot to mention you sorry